# DataTable jquery - How to remove sort icon from first column?

Tags: jquery, css, sorting, datatable, removeclass

I want to disable the sort property in dataTable API. I use bsort:false to disable sorting from all the columns.

This works good but still first column show sort icon. Why ?

```
$("#reportgrid").DataTable({
    "order": [],"bSort" : false,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
});
```

I use this code for dataTable.

[image]

Here is the snapshot of my grid. In which first column having css of sorting_asc but i already disable sorting.

So, How can i remove sort icon from first column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. bStorable false for each of your column then only icon removed.

```
$("#reportgrid").dataTable({"order": [],
    "aoColumns": [
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false }
],
"sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">'});
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post but I faced the same problem today and the below solution worked for me. It will remove the sorting icon from the first column.

```
$('#table').dataTable({
     'columnDefs': [{ 'orderable': false, 'targets': 0 }], // hide sort icon on header of first column
     'aaSorting': [[1, 'asc']] // start to sort data in second column 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect solution

Comment: Somewhy It loads sort arrows as ussual and removes it only after click the next column sort arrows.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple solution which worked in my case without any need for css is to tell DataTables to start the ordering by the second column instead of the first with the order initialization property option (check the datatable reference - [Initial order (sort) to apply to the table](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order)):

`"order": [[1, 'asc']]`

This will remove the sort icon from the first coloumn if sorting is disabled for that column.

Answer (score 2):

try this for latest version:

```
$('#reportgrid').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the datatables documentation you can use the [ordering](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering) option to enable or disable sorting of columns

```
$("#reportgrid").DataTable({
    "ordering": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
})
```

Comment: It works as same bsort:false works. But first column still shows sort icon.